# Custom field serializer / deserializer

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am able to load some entities into ElasticSearch with out-of-the box Spring Data ElasticSearch. The thing is my model classes contemplate many properties and for some of those I don't want my representation (typing) be reflected into ES.

```
@Field(serializer = MyCustomSerializer, deserializer = MyCustomDeserializer)
private SomeClass someObject;
```

I'd like, for example, for SomeClass to be serialized as a String, so I can query it as such. Also, when reading data from ES, I want to be able to write a custom deserializer (MyCustomDeserializer) to convert this String into my own model.

Is there any way I can accomplish that??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data ElasticSearch uses jackson to serialize the fields, so you could achieve custom serialization logic by defining:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyCustomDeserializer.class)
private SomeClass someObject;
```

Or configure your mapping globally in a jackson `ObjectMapper`, replacing the default `EntityMapper` from spring-data-elasticsearch. More on that  [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Custom-ObjectMapper).